# Google Cloud Vision OCR - Language hints seem to be ignored

Tags: python, google-cloud-vision

I am using the Python framework of Google Cloud Vision to OCR passports. I want to support Ukrainian now, but the system has trouble recognizing handwritten parts.

I tried to improve the results by giving language hints to the system, but it seems like those are entirely ignored.

No matter what I set there, the recognized text and the language the system detects do not change at all. So to me, it looks like it is just ignoring the hint I give.

E.g. numbers are recognized as language "en", even if I change the language hint to "de" they are still returned as language "en". Even giving random strings as a language hint isn't producing any error.

```
# [...]
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient(client_options={"api_endpoint": endpoint})
response = client.document_text_detection(
    image=vision_img, image_context={"language_hints": ["uk"]}
)
# [...]
```

Are those hints just not supported using Python?

Comment: I believe the `language_hints` doesn't restrict the recognize language, it only helps to get a better result (in some rare case). I think numbers (which are Latin character) will be automatically recognized as `en`

Answer (score 1):

As Google Cloud Vision docs mentioned:

> Providing a language hint to the service is not required, but can be done if the service is having trouble detecting the language used in your image. [[1](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/languages)]

> In most cases, an empty value yields the best results since it enables automatic language detection. For languages based on the Latin alphabet, setting language_hints is not needed. In rare cases, when the language of the text in the image is known, setting a hint will help get better results (although it will be a significant hindrance if the hint is wrong). [[2](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.vision.v1#imagecontext)]

I believe the `language_hints` attribute doesnt restrict the OCR engine to recognize in only some specified languages, but helps (as show a hint to) the engine to detect the language better (*in some rare cases*). If you give a hint the language is `de`, the engine will look at `de` but then it concludes the detected language is `en`, so it will be recognize as `en` and the language hint will be ignore.

1. That's why numbers will be automatically detect and recognized as
   `en`.
2. And as the OCR Language Support [page](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/languages#handwriting-scripts). I noticed there is
   handwriting support for Cyrl (and it's only experimental), but im not sure does Ukrainian count.
   If it doesnt, I think that's why it struggle to recognize Ukrainian
   handwritten parts. Does it recognized normal Ukrainian text normally in your app?

**Edit**: as this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129593350?pli=1) mentioned:

> Providing the language hints could improve the results in those cases. Nevertheless, providing a language hint does not mean that this language will be used exclusively.